# iis default website is not available also when i hit url like = localhost it is not showing iis image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

when i am goto iis manager, there i can't able to see the **Default website** under the "Site" submenu on left side of iis manager.

what should i do ?

Also when i am checking for IIS is working on my windows 7 computer 
steps- 1- Type Localhost on address bar and enter.
2- but is shows error like

> Not Found

HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

Please help, thanks

Comment: Even if there _is_ an image in your question, I can't see it because of firewall since I'm at work now. How about writing your question with text instead of image?

Answer (score 0):

To install IIS to serve static content
Click the Start button , click Control Panel, click Programs, and then click Turn Windows features on or off. ...
In the list of Windows features, select Internet Information Services, and then click OK.

Comment: i already did all these stuf but still i cant able to see Default web site .